# SQLite com Javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Estou conhecendo o SQLite agora, para tentar implantar em uma aplicação mobile, fiz este teste baseado em alguns códigos da web mas não consigo retornar uma gravação dos dados com sucesso, até faz o select mas retorna 0 registros, como mostra o trecho: `alert(r.rows.length);`

```
var db = openDatabase("appLocal", "1.0", "base de dados da aplicacao", 

200000);

// criando a tabela caso ela não exista
db.transaction(function(transaction){
    transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_teste ("teste" TEXT)', [], null, db.onError);
    alert("criou");
});

// aqui vai o insert
db.transaction(function(transaction){    
  transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO tb_teste(teste) VALUES('testex');", db.onSuccess, db.onError);
    alert("inseriu");
});

// consulta no banco
db.transaction(function(transaction){
    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tb_teste", [], db.getResults, db.onError);
    alert("selecionou");
});

// função callback de erro
db.onError = function(transaction, e) {
  alert("Aconteceu um erro!");
  console.log(e.message);
}

// função de callback de sucesso de insert
db.onSuccess = function(transaction, e) {
  alert("Dados Gravados com Sucesso!");
  console.log(e);
}

// função temporaria que lista resultados
db.getResults = function (transaction, r) {
    //console.log('deu certo!');
    //console.log(r);
    alert(r.rows.length);

   for(var i = 0; i < r.rows.length; i++){
       alert(r.rows.item(i)[['teste']]);
       alert("rodou");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema está acontecendo na chamada da função `transaction.executeSql` para inserir dados na tabela.

Essa função não aceita parâmetros de `callback` para erro ou sucesso (testado no Google Chrome, mas para outros browsers, pode funcionar de forma diferente).

A linha de comando para fazer o INSERT deve ficar assim:

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO tb_teste(teste) VALUES('testex');")
```

ou assim:

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO tb_teste(teste) VALUES(?);", ['testex']);
```

[Veja funcionando no jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gomiero/0g36qeg1/)

Uma dica:

Conforme a documentação [Web SQL Database - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), esta API (SQLite) está obsoleta e o seu uso não é recomendado.

Para armazenar dados no cliente, você pode utilizar:

- [Indexed Database API](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- [Web Storage](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)